# How do I express a desire to obtain a master's degree?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot

Bonjour

How can I say that I want to enroll in a master's program?  Here are a few options I've found/come up with.

1. Je veux passer un masters.
2. Je veux effectuer un masters.
3. Je veux faire un masters.

Which of these sounds the most natural?  Are there any better options that I haven's mentioned?

Comment: enroll in English is wrong *unless the university has already accepted you*. We'd say: apply for a Master's or get into a Master's program or do a Master's.

Answer (score 1):

*Master* is singular.

> *Je veux faire un master.*

or, in most contexts:

> *Je voudrais faire un master.*

Alternatively:

> *Je voudrais m'inscrire en master.*